# CSS&HTML : How to put an image(for example X/check) inside a checkbox when you hover it

Tags: css, checkbox

Good day mate, i really wanna play at the same time learn about html and css. So i would like to ask it is possible to put an image in a checkbox when its being hovered? yes just hovered not click. for example i want to put some check with opacity of .5 in a checkbox when its hovered indicating that that check will appear when you click it thank you. supposedly this is my checkbox here :

```
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="" />Example</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Short answer is, yes. Long answer, try with background-image or with a pseudo element.

Comment: okay mate thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use images, can be done with css using `:before` and `:after` with `:hover`

See example:

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #000000;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  z-index: 0;
  font: 14px/1.5em sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
}
.box {
  background: #555;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
}
p {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  content: "\00a0";
  display: inline-block;
  font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 16px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:hover:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  content: "\2713";
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  content: "\2713";
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cb">
      <label for="c1">Checkbox</label>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)